# How to test use of toLocal in Dart

Tags: unit-testing, dart, testing, timezone-offset

I would like to write a testcase to ensure use of the `toLocal` function in a Flutter app I am working on as forgetting that has been a reoccuring issue. **Note:** I am *not* asking how to test the function, I am sure the Dart developers are doing a great job on that. I want to write a testcase that ensures the function is called.

Figures, it should be as easy as something like this:

```dart
// Function I want to test
int getLocalHour(DateTime dateTime) => dateTime.toLocal().hour;

void main() {
  test('getLocalHour uses local time', () {
    final testedTime = DateTime.utc(2022, 9, 20, 12);

    expect(getLocalHour(testedTime), 14);
  });
}
```

Now you might say "Hold up, 12 o'clock utc isn't 2pm in my timezone" and you may be right! That's the problem I have; I couldn't find a reliable way of setting the timezone to use for `toLocal` to get reproducible results. In CEST, this test will run fine on my laptop, during winter, it will fail. And in the CI, it will fail all year around because it's running on a server configured to use UTC time.

Is there a way to have `toLocal` produce a predetermined output so I can ensure it's called in the places I need it to be called?

Comment: You can't do it from Dart; you would need to change the timezone on your system before executing the test.  I recommend using [`package:timezone`](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) and its `TZDateTime` class instead.

Comment: @jamesdlin That appears to allow the thing I was expecting to need; setting the timezone programmatically I mean. Any chance you could make an answer from this showing how to change the logic of my function and the test setup? Otherwise I am going to experiment with this next week and make something up on my own :) Either way, thanks for hinting me towards that package!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to local time yourself, in the test, and compare to the value of that.

```dart
void main() {
  test('getLocalHour uses local time', () {
    final testedTime = DateTime.utc(2022, 9, 20, 12);
    final testedLocalTime = testedTime.toLocal();
    
    expect(getLocalHour(testedTime), testedLocalTime.hour);
  });
}
```

That will accidentally pass if you run the test in GMT and forget to call `toLocal`. Not much to do about that.

Comment: But that would require me to replicate the logic I want to test is being used in the test itself which feels like it sort of defeats the purpose of a unit test; of course two implementations that are identical (without non-pure functions called inside) will produce the same output.

Comment: Yes. You have a functionality that you want to check is being used. You are not checking that it works correctly, because you don't actually know what that means, not unless you know in which time zone the code is actually running (or the time zone offset).

All you can check is that the result is actually "local time", whatever that might be.